# How to control number of returned rows in an SQL query, without knowing how many rows we need

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a `posts` table and a `comments` table. I want to get the first two posts from my database, along with all comments that go with them. The SQL query could look like this:

```
SELECT C.CommentId, P.PostId FROM Post AS P
    LEFT JOIN Comment AS C ON P.PostId = C.PostId
    ORDER BY P.PostId ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY
```

And that gives me this return set:

```
PostId CommentId
1      1
1      2
1      3
2      1
2      2
2      3
```

Instead of hardcoding the "6" in `FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS`, how can I write my query in such a way that I am getting all associated comments for the first two posts in my database, regardless of what the `P.PostId` value is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the asterisked line below.

```
SELECT C.CommentId, P.PostId FROM Post AS P
LEFT JOIN Comment AS C ON P.PostId = C.PostId
**where p.postID in (select top 2 postID from post order by postID)**
ORDER BY P.PostId ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT C.CommentId
     , P.PostId 
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY P.PostId  ASC) rn 
FROM Post AS P
LEFT JOIN Comment AS C ON P.PostId = C.PostId
)
SELECT CommentId
      ,PostId
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY PostId ASC
WHERE rn <= 2
```

### OR

```
SELECT CommentId
      ,PostId
FROM
 (
SELECT C.CommentId
     , P.PostId 
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY P.PostId  ASC) rn 
FROM Post AS P
LEFT JOIN Comment AS C ON P.PostId = C.PostId
ORDER BY P.PostId ASC
) A
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY PostId ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, but this `where` clause ruins it I'm afraid. We have no idea what the `Post.PostId` value is. It's auto increment and the original rows may have been deleted, giving our first row a `PostId` of, say, 5.

Comment: @MartynChamberlin this where clause is filtering on DENSE_RANK not on PostID so it should be fine :) ,  It will pick the first two PosIds it maybe (1 , 100) or (5 , 500) or (67 , 68)

Comment: To be clear, I am upvoting the DENSE_RANK approach.  Posting two different solutions in one answer is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

According to your problem statement

**Instead of hardcoding the "6" in FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS, how can I write my query in such a way that I am getting all associated comments for the first two posts in my database, regardless of what the P.PostId value is?**

Wrap this query into the stored procedure and supply bellow three parameters instead of hardcoding `OFFSET`,`ROWS` and `Top` rows

```
Declare @offset int 
Declare @rows int
Declare @top int

 with cte as 
 (
   SELECT TOP (@top) postID 
   FROM post 
    ORDER BY postID 
) 

    SELECT C.CommentId, P.PostId 
    FROM Post AS P
    LEFT JOIN Comment AS C ON P.PostId = C.PostId
    WHERE  p.postID in (select postID from cte)
    ORDER BY P.PostId ASC
    OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @rows ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. My only beef with it is that the initial pool of eligible numbers is declared inside the nested select query (that's fine, but hang on). The universe declared inside this nested query will get trimmed down to a smaller universe in the outer query. Thus, we want the nested universe to be as big as possible. Having a `@top` variable arbitrarily trim down this nested universe becomes a problem when we are focused on the Nth post set, not just the first two posts. We would have no way of knowing how big `@top` should be.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  Just kind of thinking "off the cuff" a bit here..  This has not been tested.

```
SELECT C.CommentId, P.PostId FROM Post AS P
    LEFT JOIN Comment AS C ON P.PostId = C.PostId
    WHERE P.PostId > P.PostId-2
    ORDER BY P.PostId ASC
```

Comment: I think there is a strong possibility I am just missing something here, but wouldn't this return every post, no matter what?  Isn't "WHERE P.PostId > P.PostId-2" always going to evaluate TRUE?

Comment: It should be pretty easy to SQL Fiddle this.

Comment: Yeah, it should be. Here, let me do it for you. Results are exactly as I described:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/3269

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT **top 2**
 C.CommentId, P.PostId FROM Post AS P
    LEFT JOIN Comment AS C ON P.PostId = C.PostId
    ORDER BY P.PostId ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Alas, no cigar. That gives me this error in Visual Studio:

`Msg 10741, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
A TOP can not be used in the same query or sub-query as a OFFSET.`

Very important that we maintain the ability to determine offset and row count.

Comment: `Top` can not be used with `OFFSET FETCH`